# Questions or answers containing \cs_set_eq not found

Tags: discussion, support, search

If I [search on TeX - LaTeX for `\cs_set_eq`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Ccs_set_eq), only one result is returned: ["Q: Patch font with LuaTeX"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122190/18401) whereas e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398268/18401) contains code containing `\cs_set_eq`.

Do you know what's going on?

Comment: Okay, searching for `\cs_set_eq:NN` gives more results. Strange anyway, and I guess others could fall into the same trap as I did.

Comment: conjecture: in the "found" question, the string is in the text, whereas in the "undiscovered" answer, it's in a code block.  if true, that's a distinct disadvantage for finding good answers.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed, the string in the "found" question being in the text as a code snippet. Still strange that `\cs_set_eq:NN` is found even in code blocks and not `\cs_set_eq`.

Comment: But the actual question is: _why LaTeX 3 has such a complicated syntax?_

Comment: @CarLaTeX: No, that's not the question. I find the `expl3` syntax very elegant and better suited for programming.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't know it enough to judge, till now it seems very complicated to me!

Comment: @CarLaTeX just try something complicated with standard LaTeX2e and TeX code and then do the same once in `expl3`, after that, you like it :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Searching for `xyz` finds results that are listed in the *text only* and not the *code* part, *unless* that code part is set using the `<pre>`...`</pre>` tags. So, this type of search excludes code segments that are not set via the `<pre>`...`</pre>` tags (indented by 4 spaces).

If you want to search within those segments, you need to use `code:"<code>"`. This, however, requires an exact match for a code segment. So searching for `code:"xyz"` would miss code segments with `xyzz` or `xxyz` in it.

In-line code content (those between backticks `` `<code>` ``) seem to fall within both categories.

The difference here stems (I guess) from the fact that there's two different versions of question content that is active in the background - a "raw" and a "baked" format. The latter is an HTML (or visual/display) format for representing content within the browser, while the latter is the content as-is.

You can't combine these searches, since the OR operator is only used for combining *tags* (as in, `[widgets] or [geegaws]`).

Here are some choices:

- [`\cs_set_eq`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Ccs_set_eq)

  [image]
- [`code:"\cs_set_eq:NN"`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3A%22%5Ccs_set_eq%3ANN%22)

  [image]

It is often better to search using a site-specific Google search, as in [`"cs_set_eq" site:tex.stackexchange.com`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22cs_set_eq%22+site%3Atex.stackexchange.com). However, since questions and answers are contained within the same visible page, the search results will necessarily cover both (as opposed to having a `is:question` or `is:answer` operator).

[image]

Searching is definitely not perfect on the network and takes some practice getting used to. Escaping characters may also cause issues, and this is especially true on TeX.SE where the use of `\` is prevalent.

Reference(s):

- [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/168244)
- [How to search](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching)
- [Search just code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55473/168244)