# A search of a code string within my posts doesn't work

Tags: support, code, search

I'm searching my posts which contain `\multicolumn{1}`.

I tried with:

```
code:"\multicolumn{1}" user:me
```

and

```
code:\multicolumn{1} user:me
```

but they both give 0 results, whereas there is at least one post of mine which match that conditions:
[\makecell in the header: how to get rid of the space after the last column of the table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318490/makecell-in-the-header-how-to-get-rid-of-the-space-after-the-last-column-of-th).

What am I doing wrong or how can I properly search for these posts?

Comment: Related: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7461/35864 But you used `code`. Seems you have just confirmed again that the search function here is not ideal. `user:101651 code:"multicolumn"` seems to work, Werner mentions escaping and special characters could be problematic and `\multicolumn{1}` contains three possibly problematic characters.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295440 (especially the comment) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267937

Comment: Why don't you googe it? `"carlatex" multicolumn site:tex.stackexchange.com`

Comment: @Johannes_B It doesn't work because I want to search only the `\multicolumn` followed by `{1}`.

Comment: @moewe I tried with `"..."` but it doesn't work, I'll try with SEDE, thank you both!

Comment: Googling `"carlatex" "multicolumn{1}" site:tex.stackexchange.com` gives one result (actually it reports "about 1 results" :-)

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, but the example of my question is not listed (to tell the truth, it is not listed in any other of the previously suggested ways)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to route your query through [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com). I think the reason here is the difference between the stored content of the post (what you actually typed) and the *baked* content (what is visualized through the browser). This difference is needed because of Stack Exchange accepting Markdown as input.

[This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/840246/search-for-a-specific-code-string) hopefully provides what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
 Id As [Post Link],
 *
FROM
 Posts
WHERE
 (OwnerUserId = 101651) And
 (Body LIKE '%multicolumn{1}%');
```

We search for all fields within the records of the `Posts` table, but only records where you posted something and there is `multicolumn{1}` somewhere in the body. The first field returned will be a hyperlink to the post. This would be synonymous to a regular search resembling

```
user:101651 "multicolumn{1}"
```

since `multicolumn{1}` could appear in a baked or unbaked form.

The only drawback is that SEDE is updated with roughly a one week lag.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!